# Derived XmlSerializer can not be loaded within MSTest

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, mstest

I'm facing a strange behaviour. I have an derived implementation of an .NET XmlSerializer looking like this

```
public class ASerializer : XmlSerializer
{
    public ASerializer()
        : base( typeof ( A ) ) {}
}
```

While instanciating an instance of this class within a MSTest an exception with the following message is thrown:

```
Initialization method 'ASerializerTest.Initialize' threw exception. 
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ASerializer' from assembly 'AAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'..
```

Running the Test from ReSharper Runner succeeds. Any ideas on this topic?

Thanks,
MacX

Comment: very strange --- debugging the test within the visualstudio runner also succeeds. running it doesn't.

Comment: Just wondering... *why* are you subclassing `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: in order not to box myself... instead of i want to encapsulate this step of serialization

Comment: Can you give us the full assembly name it's looking for? I suspect it might have to do with the CPU architecture you are building under.

Comment: Many thanks... works like a charm. Switched the CPU selection from "Mixed Platforms" to "Any CPU". Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPU-Selection showed "Mixed Platforms". Switched it to "Any CPU". 
Works like a charm now.

Many Thanks to [Jonathan Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/430560/jonathan-dickinson) for the hint.